# showTextTrack in Video.js 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video, video.js

I am trying to change the active caption track from JavaScript in Video.js v5.10.4. I saw a few posts about this and they all suggested to use `showTextTrack`, but when I execute the command it says that `showTextTrack is not a function`. I currently have the following code

```
var video = videojs('video');
var first_track_id = video.textTracks().tracks_[0].id; // this returns vjs_track_399
video.showTextTrack(first_track_id, "captions"); // this returns the error above
```

Is there any other way to accomplish what I am trying to do, or what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`showTextTracks()` was for video.js 4. Now you just set the mode of the track to `showing`:

```
video.textTracks()[0].mode = 'showing';
```